# error installing coffeescript on mac 10.7.2

Tags: macos, node.js, installation, coffeescript, npm

Node and npm are both installed and up to date but keep getting this error when trying to install coffeescript. I am still new to programming so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
test-macbook:~ Test$ npm -v
1.1.0-3
test-macbook:~ Test$ node -v
v0.6.8
test-macbook:~ Test$ npm install -g coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm
npm ERR! error installing coffee-script@1.2.0

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Dylan
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.8
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Dylan/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is fairly clear:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

You can't install it in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` because you don't have the necessary permissions. Try using `sudo`:

```
dylan-hermans-macbook:~ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

---

The npm author recommends not using `sudo` because packages can run arbitrary commands so `sudo npm install` is dangerous. He suggests switching the ownership of `/usr/local` to your user. I think that's horribly advice that just gives you a false sense of security: if a package can run arbitrary commands then it can mess with your home directory (including all your personal data, executables, config and startup files, ...) regardless of `sudo` or who owns `/usr/local` so not using `sudo` really doesn't do much for you. If you don't trust a package then don't install it; if you don't trust a package then how can you even use it? The `/usr/local` tree is still a system directory tree and OSX is still a multi-user operating system.

IMO a much better solution is twofold:

1. Don't install or use any packages that you don't trust. If you install it then you're trusting that code to be you (unless you're always going to run it in a jail of some sort but if you're going to those lengths you're probably better off writing the code yourself).
2. Leave `sudo` and `/usr/local` alone and install it all inside your home directory. You'll be subject to most of the same dangers as using `sudo` or changing the `/usr/local` ownership but at least you won't be picking up bad habits.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware the solution was so simple. I'll be sure to keep this in mind for similar problems that I encounter in the future.

Comment: Please see the answer from Tim Schaub, below, for the proper way to handle this.

Comment: This is not a solution in any way, the solution is to give the user to access to '/usr/local' as @TimSchaub puts it correctly.

Comment: @AvinashR: If you don't like it, downvote it. I find the idea of `chown`ing `/usr/local` to be ridiculous and Isaac Schlueter's advice is quite frankly stupid: if you don't trust a package then why would you install it at all? If a package can run arbitrary scripts then it can do all sorts of fun things to your home directory.

Comment: actually Issac's [advice](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm) is better than alternative of using `sudo`, why? [the lesser you run code in elevated privileges the better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). The best way to kick off sudo from the command is to give the user access to the `/usr/local` (a.k.a `chown`) or to create a group that owns it (say _local-admin_) and add the user to the group.(which requires `sudo`, if I'm right)

Comment: BTW, @muistooshort I'm not telling this just by reading the wikipedia article I used above, you can see that other people are having same mentality [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21155)

Comment: @AvinashR: I think the best thing would be if installation came in two steps: one step builds things (which could be done by a super-low privilege user such as `nobody`), one step does the installation solely by copying files or executing a limited set of well defined commands each of which would require confirmation. So no scripts would be run by a privileged user during installation and only a small set of safe-ish things could be done with explicit permission. I still see `/usr/local` as part of the OS so it should be read-only for non-root users.

Comment: @muistooshort answer is right on target. Saying that chown of /usr/local is better than sudo in any way is disingenuous. With sudo you make explicit your intentions of elevating privileges, with chowning /usr/local you will be at the mercy of whatever packages you install. No one should ever own /usr or subdirectories except root suggesting otherwise breaks the unix security model.

Comment: Option two looks like an excellent solution to this.  What would the command look like to install into your home directory?

Comment: @MatthewWalker: I'm not sure off the top of my head, I used Cinderella and Brew to install everything and that sensibly puts everything in `~/Developer`.

Answer (score 13):

Following [the advice](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm) of nmp author Isaac Z. Schlueter:

> I strongly encourage you not to do package management with sudo!

Instead of `sudo npm install ...` you could instead change permissions on your `/usr/local` directory:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

After doing this once, you should be able to `npm install ...` (without sudo).

Comment: you are absolutely right - this is the whole point of using package managers like npm or homebrew :)

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is an older thread, but I just ran across this and wanted to update the last answer.

Changing the owner of the entire /usr/local directory is a horrible answer to this question.  There's no reason at all that you should do that.

If you look at the error message from npm, it's being denied write permissions on /usr/local/lib/node_modules/  I know that after installing node and npm on OS X Mavericks, its default owner is a non-existent user.

```
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 24561        wheel     102 Jan 23 14:17 node_modules
```

If you're just running node/npm on your local development machine, just change the owner of the node_modules folder to your user:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Then you can install modules with npm without sudo and without changing the owner of /usr/lib from root, as it should be.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules` avoids the problem of users accidentally entering the wrong username.