# CoffeeScript Installing with NPM and Node

Tags: node.js, installation, coffeescript, npm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error installing coffeescript on mac 10.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027285/error-installing-coffeescript-on-mac-10-7-2)

At the moment, I am trying to install CoffeeScript on my computer. I have node.js version 0.6.7 and npm 1.1.0-beta-10. When i run the command npm install -g coffee-script, it shows this error.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.2.0.tgz
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm
npm ERR! error installing coffee-script@1.2.0
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.0.1
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Solomon
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Solomon/npm-debug.log
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Run it as root. Your user doesn't have permissions to write to /usr/local/lib/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'

That means you dont have access, so run as root

`$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script`

(Bonus points for alternatively, not using coffeescript (it's a horrible thing))

Comment: Disagree on the anti-CoffeeScript part of the answer, but upvoting the rest of it.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham someone has to fight the good fight, before we lose javascript :(

Comment: coffeescript IS javascript. Also, my issue was that the name of coffeescript changed to "coffee-script" instead of being one word.

Answer (score 1):

The `permission denied` part is your hint that the installer needs privileges that it doesn't have.  Try running as root, i.e.

```
sudo npm install coffee-script
```