# How to install jasmine-node (without using 'sudo' ideally)?

Tags: node.js, root, npm, jasmine, jasmine-node

So I'm a pretty spoiled rubyist and basically never have to install anything using sudo anymore.  I've installed node.js and npm (granted, using the Mac 64-bit .pkg, which could have done gosh knows what on my system) and they work fine.

Now, executing the following:
`npm install jasmine-node -g`

Doesn't work and says, "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator." which I take to mean `sudo npm install jasmine-node -g`

Doing: `npm install jasmine-node` (*not* globally) works fine, but doesn't setup my path correctly, doesn't run from the command line, etc.

**How *should* I install jasmine-node?**  `cd` to `/usr/local/bin` and install it (without the '-g' option) there?  Use homebrew?  Or use the `sudo ...` command I listed above?

Thanks.

/UPDATE: As mentioned above, I installed node.js & npm on my Lion OS X Mac (64-bit) using the universal installer and here are my node/npm listings in /usr/local/bin, in case they're of help:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 24561  wheel       355 Apr 11  2012 /usr/local/bin/node-waf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 24561  wheel  18930304 Oct 25 14:07 /usr/local/bin/node
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root   admin        38 Nov 12 10:00 /usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

Also, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219572/492404), which is one other option (in addition to the three I presented above).

Please let me know which method is recommended (again, ideally without using 'sudo' is my preference).

/END UPDATE

Here is what doing it with `-g` (globally) returns (not using `sudo`):

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node/-/jasmine-node-1.0.26.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node/-/jasmine-node-1.0.26.tgz
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ 'DirWriter._create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23)',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jasmine-node" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/brad/play/troles
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.65
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node'
npm ERR! fstream_stack DirWriter._create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23)
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/brad/play/troles/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the node and npm community has finally (in the past year) worked out a method for installing npm and node without needing to use sudo.

Since I'm on Mac OS X, I found [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919540/492404) worked for me to `uninstall` node & npm, then I just used `brew` to install npm (which automatically gives one node as well). You may need to sudo uninstall, btw, if you sudo'ed to install.

If the above linked instructions don't work, try the top-voted (1500+ votes) answer to do it a bit more manually.

Now having done that, jasmine-node installs just fine w/o sudo, any chowning, or any permissions wrangling.  Just run `npm install jasmine-node -g` and all is well.

Answer (score 5):

When not using the `-g` (global install) option, "[executables go in `./node_modules/.bin/`](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)".

I don't use the `-g` myself. If you really don't want to install it globally, you can install jasmine-node in your $HOME and add `$HOME/node_modules/.bin` to the $PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume I hadn't found that link in spite of enough googling that you'd think I'd have run across it!  That explains it pretty well.

I guess the answer is (according to that post) that most people just do install it globally using sudo.  I think I'll use your suggestion and add `$HOME/node_modules/.bin` to my path, unless I see a better best practice suggestion in the next couple of days--thanks!

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted, though I would prefer a better solution--if anyone finds one, please do add!

Comment: Btw, I found an answer to this question ~ 2.5 yrs after I asked it. That answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30204033/492404).

Answer (score 3):

I just changed the ownership of all the folders node was concerned with.

```
sudo chown -R my_account_name /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo chown -R my_account_name /usr/local/lib/node/
sudo chown -R my_account_name /usr/local/include/node/
```

I don't really know if that's bad practice, but I don't really give a damn.

Comment: it's bad practice but well said sir!

Answer (score 0):

When you run npm install -g somepackage, you may get an EACCES error asking you to run the command again as root/Administrator. It's a permissions issue.

It's **easy to fix**, open your terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal)

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

** I strongly recommend you to not use the package management with sudo (sudo npm -g install something), because you can get some issues later **

Reference: http://foohack.com/2010/08/intro-to-npm/

**** Recommended way ****

The reason is because this can cause permissions problems with lots of other apps, so I'd suggest not doing this.
**A better solution when you are installing in global:**

> sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm